# How to arrive at these conditions for 2x2 SPD matrices?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, positive-definite

Claim: For the matrix   $M = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & c \\
   c & b \\
  \end{array} } \right]$
 to be symmetric (trivial) and positive definite: $a>0$ and $ab-c^2>0$
where a,b and c $\epsilon \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt at a proof:

If M is SPD then $z^TMz > 0$ for any real valued 2d vector z.

Let:
$z = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   x  \\
   y  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

$z^TMz = ax^2 + 2cxy + by^2$

so

$ax^2 + 2cxy + by^2 > 0$

should give me those conditions,although this is where I am stuck. I can see something that looks kind of right when I rearrange to:

$(\sqrt{a}x+\sqrt{b}y)^2 +2xy(c-\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}) > 0$

but don't know where to go from there.

I have also tried finding the eigenvalues of M and then forcing them to be > 0, and that did lead to the second condition ($ab-c^2$) but not the first.

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider $z$ to be $z := \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. For the second property: What do you know about the determinant of an spd matrix?

Comment: If I take y=0, I do arrive at a>0. and the determinant of an SPD matrix must be >0?  and det(M) = ab-c^2?

Comment: As you stated: " If M is SPD then $z^TMz > 0$", since this is true for arbitrary z, it is also true for $z := \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. So we compute $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T M \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = a >0$. And yes, and SPD Matrix has positive determinant and the determinant is given by $ab-c^2$.

Comment: Excellent! As an extension, how would I know that aren't further conditions on a, b, c that must be satisfied?

Comment: Or rather, how do I know that there isn't another z that breaks that condition..? I know that the statment is true for one z vector, but how do I know it for all z?

Comment: The above statements hold for all SPD matrices with entries $\mathbb{R}$. We never used any properties of $a,b,c$ except for these elements to be real when showing our claims.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the 4th characterization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations).

> $M \in M^{\text{sym}}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is positive definite if and only if its leading principal minors are positive. The $k$th leading principal minor is the determinant of its upper-left $k\times k$ submatrix.

This theorem is called [Sylvester criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) and its proof can be found at the linked page.